# emacs ess crashes when trying to access h_elp

Tags: r, emacs, ess

My emacs/ess session crashes when I try to access help. This happens if I have two packages loaded with the same functions; for example:

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
?month
```

In Rgui interface pops out and asks to choose from which packages I want help. Emacs just crashes. Similar issues happens with install.packages, but there is a way to specify mirror [Is there a way to install R packages using emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630246/is-there-a-way-to-install-r-packages-using-emacs)
Is there a similar trick with help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there is no full proof solution for time being as nobody really understands why these crashes happen. I assume you are on windows, right?

There are plans in ESS to completely internalize all the help (and other) calls in order not to depend on R dialogs. Hopefully in the next version.

For time being put this into your .Rprofile

```
tis <- utils:::index.search
formals(tis)[["firstOnly"]] <- TRUE
assignInNamespace("index.search", tis, "utils")
```

It basically makes help system to pick the first package with the found topic. In your case month help page in data.table package will be ignored. Not a big deal as common topic names are quite rare anyways.

Answer (score 3):

I found out that starting library(tcltk) solves this problem. Menu appears even after it is called from emacs+ess. I added library(tcltk) to my Rprofile.site and now everything works great, install.packages() and accessing help when multiple packages load same function